# I have installed lightgbm successfully but can't run in jupyter

Tags: python, macos, terminal, jupyter-notebook

I use anaconda to run jupyter and the path is:

```
/Users/Kum/anaconda/bin
```

I installed lightgbm successfully below this path:

```
drwxr-xr-x  22 Kum  staff   748B Feb 11 09:11 LightGBM
-rwxr-xr-x   1 Kum  staff   147B Jun 16  2016 ipython
-rwxr-xr-x   1 Kum  staff   147B Jun 16  2016 ipython2
-rwxr-xr-x   1 Kum  staff    11K Jun 16  2016 isympy
-rwxr-xr-x   1 Kum  staff   133B Jun 16  2016 jsonschema
-rwxr-xr-x   1 Kum  staff   149B Jun 16  2016 jupyter
-rwxr-xr-x   1 Kum  staff   108B Jun 16  2016 jupyter-console
-rwxr-xr-x   1 Kum  staff   176B Jun 16  2016 jupyter-kernelspec
-rwxr-xr-x   1 Kum  staff   159B Jun 16  2016 jupyter-migrate
-rwxrwxr-x   1 Kum  staff   113B Jun 16  2016 jupyter-nbconvert
-rwxr-xr-x   1 Kum  staff   152B Jun 16  2016 jupyter-nbextension
-rwxr-xr-x   1 Kum  staff   150B Jun 16  2016 jupyter-notebook
```

Under LightGBM:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 Kum  staff   3.1K Feb 11 09:10 CMakeLists.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 Kum  staff   1.1K Feb 11 09:10 LICENSE
drwxr-xr-x  12 Kum  staff   408B Feb 11 09:10 R-package
-rw-r--r--   1 Kum  staff   3.9K Feb 11 09:10 README.md
drwxr-xr-x   6 Kum  staff   204B Feb 11 09:11 build
drwxr-xr-x   4 Kum  staff   136B Feb 11 09:10 docker
drwxr-xr-x  12 Kum  staff   408B Feb 11 09:10 docs
drwxr-xr-x  10 Kum  staff   340B Feb 11 09:10 examples
drwxr-xr-x   3 Kum  staff   102B Feb 11 09:10 include
-rwxr-xr-x   1 Kum  staff   1.0M Feb 11 09:11 lib_lightgbm.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 Kum  staff   982K Feb 11 09:11 lightgbm
drwxr-xr-x   4 Kum  staff   136B Feb 11 09:10 pmml
drwxr-xr-x   8 Kum  staff   272B Feb 11 10:19 python-package
drwxr-xr-x  11 Kum  staff   374B Feb 11 09:10 src
drwxr-xr-x   4 Kum  staff   136B Feb 11 09:10 tests
drwxr-xr-x   5 Kum  staff   170B Feb 11 09:10 windows

anaconda/bin/LightGBM  master ✔
```

When I code:

```
import lightgbm as lgm
```

Got an error:

```
ImportError: No module named lightgbm
```

How to solve this....I'm so sad.XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you go through the [lightgbm installation guides](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/tree/master/python-package). Then try `conda list` to check if `lightgbm` is in the installed package list.

If the module is not installed using `conda` or `pip`, it's possible that your module is not add to the python path.

You can either config it manually by modifying the env in the beginning of your Python session, or use `jupyter notebook/Python` just under the module directory.

Comment: Yeah.I checked the path and solved the problem.Thx.
I did't put the packages in the right path.There are two versions python in my mac. @Neo X

Comment: I am using Spyder in Anaconda. Should I put the lightgbm package in the Spyder folder ?

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vVas.png)Create a new environment in conda according to requirements shown in lightgbm and than create a environment list in jupyter and use according to your package by changing in kernel setting it will work fine.

> How to create new env?

```
conda create --n py37_64 python=3.7
```

Also download according 32 bit or 64 bit for lightgbm 64 bit is used for that:

```
config --env --set subdir win--64
```

and activate particular env here it is py37_64 so command will be:

```
activate py37_64
```

and install lightgbm:

```
 pip install lightgbm
```

Now see the magic and use this env in your jupyter notebook.

```
conda install nb_conda
```

For using this kernels in notebook you have to deactivate env and activate it again

Now see your notebook

Here you can see in image im actually using this now you can switch kernels according to your requirement.